# Is there a pushbutton that does what a latching relay can do?

Tags: switches

Is there a small (around 1 cubic inch) pushbutton that does the same function as an NVR (No Voltage Release) switch or a latching relay?
Functions needed:
-Must press button when circuit loses electricity to prevent automatic starting
-Preferably a normally-open momentary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they appear to exist for the obvious applications (smallish woodworking machinery etc.). [Here](https://www.e-switch.com/system/asset/product_line/data_sheet/33/KJD17.pdf) is a datasheet.

[image]